# SQL - Union with case when and group by - HELP needed

Tags: sql, case, union

I'm working with my first union cases, and I don't understand how should I overcome the following issue.
Will appreciate the masters' help :)

The query :)

```
select Team, sum(Scored) as Scored, sum(Received) as Received
from 
(select  HomeTeam as Team, (case when HomeScore > 1 then sum(HomeScore) else 0 end) as Scored
from Matches as a
group by HomeTeam, HomeScore
Union
select  AwayTeam as Team, ( case when AwayScore>1 then sum(AwayScore) else 0 end) as Received
from Matches
 group by AwayTeam, AwayScore)  DERIVED GROUP BY Team
```

the error :(

`Invalid column name 'Received'.`

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSkSe.png)

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMkYA.png)
(I'm halfway through, my query doesn't hold all fields)

thank you kind sirs

---

Updated Query

```
select Team, sum(Scored) as Scored, sum(Received) as Received
from 
(select  HomeTeam as Team, (case when HomeScore > 0 then sum(HomeScore) else 0 end) as Scored,
( case when AwayScore>0 then sum(AwayScore) else 0 end) as Received
from Matches
group by HomeTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore
Union all
select  AwayTeam as Team,  ( case when AwayScore>0 then sum(AwayScore) else 0 end) as Received,
(case when HomeScore > 0 then sum(HomeScore) else 0 end) as Scored
from Matches
group by AwayTeam, AwayScore, HomeScore)  DERIVED GROUP BY Team
```

Still, the sum of Scored and received is incorrect

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMkYA.png)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: As the error mesage states, there is no `Received` column in `DERIVED`. You have `Team` and `Scored` only in the first part of union, and you have no `Scored` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may update your query to -

```
select Team, sum(Scored) as Scored, sum(Received) as Received
  from (select HomeTeam as Team,
               SUM(case when HomeScore > 0 then HomeScore else 0 end) as Scored,
               NULL     -- For sum(Received)
          from Matches as a
         group by HomeTeam
         Union
        select AwayTeam,
               NULL,  -- For sum(Scored)
               SUM(case when AwayScore>0 then AwayScore else 0 end) as Received
          from Matches
         group by AwayTeam) DERIVED
 GROUP BY Team
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm receiving the following error 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 315
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 323
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Yul, Please Try now.